# Printing handled text in the file

Tags: c++, file, c++11, io

Programm creates two files. 
When im entering text in the console and then printing it to file everything is OK, But when i'm reading this file, handling text (swaping first and last letters in every word) and then printing handled text in the new file, i've got:

texT

rof

example

gomethins

***instead of***

**String 1:** *Text rof example*

**String 2:** *gomethins*

How i can print text in new file like in original?

```
void create_file()
{
    ofstream file_for_writing;
    file_for_writing.open("file_w.txt");
    const int n = 80;
    int str_num = 0;
    char ch1[n];
    char sp[] = " ";
//  cout << "Сколько строк вы желаете ввести? " << endl;
//  cin >> str_num;
    cout << "Введите, пожалуйста, текст: " << endl;
//  cin.getline(ch1, n);

    for (; ; )
    {
        /*
        cin.get(ch1);
        if (ch1 == '\n') continue;
        else if (ch1 == ' ') break;
        */
        gets_s(ch1);

//      if (ch1[n-1] == '\n') continue;
         if ( ! ch1[0] ) break;
        file_for_writing << endl << ch1;

    //  cin.getline(sp, n);

    }


    system("pause");
//  cin.getline(ch1, n);

    cout << "Введенный текст:" << endl << ch1;

    //
    //while (strlen(ch1))
    //{
    //  file_for_writing << ch1;
    //}

}
void handle_file()
{
    cout << "Меняем местами первую и последнюю буквы в словах: " << endl;
    string s;
    ifstream ifs("file_w.txt");
    ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("handled.txt");
    if (ifs.is_open())
    {
        s.assign((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs.rdbuf())), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        cout << "Оригинальный текст:" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << s << endl;
        cout << endl;
        ifs.close();
    }

    stringstream ss(s);
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Обработанный текст:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    while (ss >> s) {
        char chs[80];
        swap(s.back(), s.front());
        strcpy(chs, s.c_str());
            cout << endl << chs;
            ofs << endl << chs;
    }
}
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(0, "RUS");
    create_file();
    system("cls");
    handle_file();
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: how not to put all the text in the string stream, but each line, and then extract the words, word handling, then write the processed line to the file, and so all the rows from a file?

Comment: Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

The expected output you give, compared with the actual output, seems to point to this piece of code as the source of your problem:

```
while (ss >> s) {
    char chs[80];
    swap(s.back(), s.front());
    strcpy(chs, s.c_str());
        cout << endl << chs;
        ofs << endl << chs;
}
```

With each word you output to the file, you're also adding `endl`, that is why you get each word in a separate line regardless of the line distribution they had in the original file. I suggest you use two nested loops, one that reads lines with another loop inside that processes each word in that given line. For example:

```
string line;    
while (ss.getline(line)) {
    stringstream line_stream(line);
    while(line_stream >> s) {
        char chs[80];
        swap(s.back(), s.front());
        strcpy(chs, s.c_str());
        cout << chs;
        ofs << chs;
    }
    cout << endl;
    ofs << endl;
}
```

This is an example program that takes a file name and prints each line individually:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main () {

    using namespace std;

    cout << "File name: ";
    string file_name;
    cin >> file_name;
    // to open a file with an std::string as name you need c++11
    ifstream file(file_name);

    string line, word;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        while (ss >> word) {
            cout << word; 
        }
        cout << "-- line --" << endl;
    }   

return 0;
}
```